# If $\left(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right)$ is bounded then $(b_n)$ is also bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be sequences of positive real numbers, not necessarily convergent.

**Question.** If the sequence $\left( \tfrac{a_n}{b_n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded that is there is $\alpha>0$ such that
$$
\frac{a_n}{b_n} \leq \alpha,\; \forall \; n \in \mathbb{N} \tag{1}
$$
then $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{n}}$ is bounded?

If true, then  $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{n}}$ is also bounded, since
$$
a_n \leq \alpha \cdot b_n,\; \forall \; n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
But, it is true? If think so, because if $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded then I think that a "blow-up" occours in the quocient $\frac{a_n}{b_n} $, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough, contradicting $(1)$. This make senses? There is a counterexample? Or how to prove?

Comment: $1$, $1/2$, $1/3$,... is a counterexample to this. Its bounded by 1 but the denominators grow without bound.

Comment: "If think so, because if $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is unbounded then I think that a "blow-up" occours in the quocient $\frac{a_n}{b_n} $, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ large enough, contradicting $(1)$."  ---- Have you tried any examples?  Which one gave you this intuition?

Comment: Another example, pick $a_n=b_n$, then $\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$ is bounded but $b_n$ can be anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.

Let $a_n = 1$ and $b_n = n$, then $n$ is unbounded but their ratio is bounded above by $1$.